# WPF MVVM How can i bind a property to comboBox which changes context query?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have an WPF view with one Combobox and one DataGrid. I use Entity Framework database first context as a log-term context in my app.
Let's say, this context wold be `Global.DbContext`.
My entites created by EF are: `Log` and `Client`.
In my XAML i have such bindigs:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource = {Binding LogEntries} />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" SelectedItem = {Binding SelectedClient} DisplayMemberPath="fullDomainName"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

In my view model i have these properties (i use Catel Framework, so the properties look a bit strange):

```
public ObservableCollection<Log> LogEntries
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<Log>>(LogEntriesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LogEntriesProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData LogEntriesProperty = RegisterProperty("LogEntries", typeof(ObservableCollection<Log>), null);

 public ObservableCollection<Client> Clients
    {
        get { return GetValue<ObservableCollection<Client>>(ClientsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClientsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData ClientsProperty = RegisterProperty("Clients", typeof(ObservableCollection<Client>), null);



    public Client SelectedClient
    {
        get { return GetValue<Client>(SelectedClientProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedClientProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData SelectedClientProperty = RegisterProperty("SelectedClient", typeof(Client), null);
```

and a constructor:

```
public LogWindowViewModel()
    {


        Global.DbContext.Clients.Load();
        Clients = Global.DbContext.Clients.Local;

        var qry = Global.DbContext.Logs.Where(c => c.client_id == SelectedClient.client_id);
        qry.Load();
        LogEntries = new ObservableCollection<Log>(qry);
    }
```

which is not working, because at the time of constructor execution a `SelectedClient` is null. I want my dbset to contain LogEntries only by selected client (both of clients and logs tables in db have a client_id field). How can i achieve that?
I undestand that my constructor code is completely wrong, but i can't figure out what to do in context of 'pure MVVM' approach. Please help me if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right this is the way I would do it:

1) Create new instances of the ObserableCollections in the constructor so the binding will be established.

2) move the code to fill the LogEntry List to the Setter of SelectedClient

```
 public Client SelectedClient
{
    get { return GetValue<Client>(SelectedClientProperty); }
    set { 
             SetValue(SelectedClientProperty, value);
             if(value == null)
             {
                 return;
             }
             var qry = Global.DbContext.Logs.Where(c => c.client_id ==   value.client_id);
            qry.Load();
            LogEntries.Clear();
            foreach(var entry in qry)
            {
                LogEntries.Add(entry);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: still getting null-reference exception, because SelectedClient is null.(It was not me who downvoted your answer by the way =))

Comment: If you get the null exception in the setter, just add an if(value != null). WPF might set SelectedItem to null because no Item is selected

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, my example code should be in the setter of SelectedClient. I have written this in text but the sample code was in the Setter of Clients. Just fixed it ...